# How to send a static package to private poudriere repository (freebsd)

Tags: freebsd

I create many packages to freebsd when i develop my applications and scripts. after developing i make the binary package to freebsd using the command "pkg create".

After use this command is created a package with extension ".txz" and this package can be installed using the "pkg add".

I would like of install this package using the "pkg install", send this ".txz" to my private poudriere repo, so I do not have to manually copy to each device I want to install. but i whish send only the package or the folder used to make the package this is possible? if yes, how?

This is the link used to make the package: http://lastsummer.de/creating-custom-packages-on-freebsd/